# What cloud IDE could I use for an open source Python Django project that is free or can be installed on a VPS?

Tags: gratis, python, ide, cloud-service

I have a project of open source website using Python Django.

Since I'm developing from various computers I need an IDE in the cloud.

Since it is a nonprofit project it has to be free.

I can use a hosted IDE or host it on my VPS.

I need to be able to run a test environment and debug the code.

The code will be shared on GitHub.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Gitpod.io is free for open-source and has excellent python support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Does it meet the other requirements in the question?